# Cannot figure out logic to update a table

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have below table.

TABLE: ABCD

[image]

B column have value 1 whenever there is a change in A column. Now I have to update the table like below. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: (1) Oracle and Teradata are different databases.  Tag the question with the database you are really using.  (2) If the A values are sequential and start at 1, you an just set `B` to `A - 1`

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to stored values computed from the tables. (For example if the A=1 rows are deleted, all B values are invalid.) Create a view instead, or use triggers.)

Comment: Based on your example it's `B=A-1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set b = (select sum(t2.b) from t t2 where t2.A <= t.A);
```

This is standard SQL and should work in either Oracle or Teradata.

Comment: If you need to have changes part-way through an `A` group then it will not apply it just to the current and all subsequent rows but will apply it to the preceding rows in the group as well. Not sure if this is a requirement for the OP though as the sample data does not show this case.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a slightly more complicated example (where the changes in `B` are not correlated to the changes in `A`):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ABCD( A, B ) AS
SELECT 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```
UPDATE ABCD t1
SET    b = (
             SELECT sm
             FROM   (
               SELECT ROWID AS id,
                      SUM( b ) OVER ( ORDER BY a, ROWNUM ) AS sm
               FROM   ABCD
             ) t2
             WHERE t1.ROWID = t2.ID
           );
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM ABCD;

A B
- -
1 0
1 0
1 1
2 2
2 2
3 2
3 3
3 3
```

*(Note: This is an Oracle solution; I have no idea if it will or won't work in Teradata.)*